# Error on maximum number of Files 

Tags: c#

is there any way to throw new exception on maxmium number of files in a directory ?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please be more specific, and read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Comment: What were you trying to do when you hit the maximum number of files in a directory? Writing new files?

Comment: I guess there will be an exception, or an error on the creation of the next file by the system. Do you mean a software-defined limit? What do you want to do on this exception? Write the file elsewhere? Then just structure your directories upfront to avoid this situation (with date, or some counter in the directory name)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is none:

you can catch it with a more generic

```
System.IO.IOException
```

And read the (underlying) message you could throw a self written Exception from that point.

**UPDATE** 
[I just learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769062/what-if-directoryinfo-getfiles-length-exceeds-int32-maxvalue) . that you use the

```
   bool isfull = info.GetFiles().LongLength == 4.294.967.295
```

property. Unfortunately it will eat all your memory.

Therefore using

```
   DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles().Count()
```

perhaps in a chunked manner could be a better approach

fyi:

- 65,534 for FAT32
- 4,294,967,295 FOR NTFS

([source](http://www.ntfs.com/ntfs_vs_fat.htm))

Comment: My guess is that your application will run out of RAM before it ever gets to assign `true` to the `isFull` variable. Just holding the references to these 4 billion entries in the array would consume 4GB, and that's excluding the actual strings...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know specifically about C#, but I know Java doesn't have a specific exception or error to throw for a full drive. I suggest simply making your own exception class and using that. I suggest calling it a `FullDirectoryError` or `DirectoryOverflowError`, assuming it's serious enough to be called an error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
public static void checkFileNumber(string directoryToCheck, int maxNumber )
{
    if ( Directory.Exists( directoryToCheck ) )
    {
        if ( Directory.GetFiles( directoryToCheck ).Length > maxNumber )
        {
            throw new Exception("Too many files in " + directoryToCheck);
        }
    }
}
```

Be sure to `use System.IO;` :-)

Comment: what is maximum number of a directory ?

Comment: The code I posted throws an exception when in there are more than maxNumber of files (real files and not directories) in directoryToCheck .

Comment: Now I understood: The limit is dependent on the file system type. A quick serach revealed these limits: FAT16 512 entries, FAT32 65,534 entries, NTFS 4,294,967,295 entries

Answer (score 0):

Throwing exceptions is an expensive action; when you can avoid it, please do so. Try to program defensively if it is possible. But when throwing one, you have to supply a matching catch on a specific exception.

Like Casper Kleijne said, you could catch on IOException but why in the first place would you want to catch anyway ? What is the compensating action in the catch ?

Please supply some more info what you want to achieve with it.