# What if DirectoryInfo.GetFiles().Length exceeds Int32.MaxValue?

Tags: c#, asp.net, 64-bit, filesystems

By another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766540/error-on-maximum-number-of-files/3767265#3767265) about the maximum number of files in a folder, I noticed 
that

```
 DirectoryInfo.GetFiles().Length
```

is returning a System.In32, but the Maximum value of a Int32 is

```
 2.147.483.647  (Int32.MaxValue)
```

while on NTFS (an many other filesystems) the maximum number of files can go far beyond that.

on NTFS it is

```
 4.294.967.295 single files in one folder (probably an Uint32)
```

Which leads me to the interesting question:

**Is it possible to get the number of files in a folder on NTFS with the .NET framework, when the number of files exceeds the Int32.MaxValue, in an elegant and performing manner?**

*note: this is not a matter of why. and I know, those are a lot of files ;)*

Comment: Do you really have a requirement to store more than int.MaxValue files in a folder ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a `LongLength` property on `Array`, which returns the length as a `long`. Anyway, if `GetFiles` returns more than `Int32.MaxValue` items, you will have problems anyway... like an `OutOfMemoryException` ;)

When you don't actually need the number of items, I suggest you use the `EnumerateFiles` method instead (introduced in 4.0). It doesn't fetch all the filenames in memory at once, instead it fetches them one by one

Comment: so I have to loop trough sets of In32.Max (or less) and add results of DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles().Count(), like in a nice and gentle manner?

Comment: If you only want the number of files (not the filenames themselves), yes, EnumerateFiles will probably be more efficient (and will use much less memory)